# Counting 0-9 with Verilog with Frequency Divided Clock for FPGA

Tags: verilog

I am trying to display the values counted from 0-9 on my FPGA (Cyclone V board) using a 1Hz clock. The issue is that the input clock is 50Mhz (native to the FPGA) and I am unsure if am performing the frequency divider correctly. Or, maybe there is an issue with my always blocks.

KEY0 is going to act as a reset, so long as KEY0 is pressed I want the counter to display 0 constantly.

KEY1 is going to be my 'freerun' mode. So long as this key is pressed I want to enable the board to count from 0-9 and start back at 0 continuously.

If neither are pressed, I guess it should stop counting and freeze, or revert back to 0.

The code I've written performs the frequency division by a factor of 2N. Therefore, you will see that I used N = 25,000,000 to achieve a 1Hz clock.

My issue: when I upload my code to the FPGA I only see the value 0 displayed on my hex display and no buttons perform any actions. I am looking for hints, tips, or solutions that may fix my code and enable me to see the 0-9 counting functionality on my FPGA.

```
module displayingTime #(parameter WIDTH = 26, parameter N = 25000000) (input clk, resetKEY0, freerunKEY1, output clk_out, output reg carry, output reg [6:0] HEX_0, output reg[7:0] count);

    reg Maxval = 8'b00001001;
    reg [WIDTH-1:0] r_reg;
    wire [WIDTH-1:0] r_nxt;
    reg clk_track;
    assign r_nxt = r_reg + 1;
    assign clk_out = clk_track;
    integer i;

    always @ (posedge clk or posedge resetKEY0) begin
        if ( resetKEY0 ) begin
            r_reg <= 0;
            clk_track <= 1'b0;
        end else if ( r_nxt == N ) begin
            r_reg <= 0;
            clk_track <= ~clk_track;
        end else
            r_reg <= r_nxt;
    end 

    always @ (posedge clk_out or posedge resetKEY0) begin
        if ( resetKEY0 ) begin
            count <= 0;
            carry <= 0;
        end else if ( freerunKEY1 )
            if ( count < Maxval ) begin
                count <= count + 8'd1;
                carry <= 0;
        end else begin
            count <= 0;
            carry <= 1;
        end
    end

    always @ (*) begin
        case (count)
        // count is 0, hex_0 displays 0
        8'd0 : HEX_0 = 7'b1000000;
        // count is 1, hex_0 displays 1
        8'd1 : HEX_0 = 7'b1111001;
        // count is 2, hex_0 displays 2
        8'd2 : HEX_0 = 7'b0100100;
        // count is 3, hex_0 displays 3
        8'd3 : HEX_0 = 7'b0110000;
        // count is 4, hex_0 displays 4
        8'd4 : HEX_0 = 7'b0011001;
        // count is 5, hex_0 displays 5
        8'd5 : HEX_0 = 7'b0010010;
        // count is 6, hex_0 displays 6
        8'd6 : HEX_0 = 7'b0000010;
        // count is 7, hex_0 displays 7
        8'd7 : HEX_0 = 7'b1111000;
        // count is 8, hex_0 displays 8
        8'd8 : HEX_0 = 7'b0000000;
        // count is 9, hex_0 displays 9
        8'd9 : HEX_0 = 7'b0011000;
        default : HEX_0 = 7'b1000000;
        endcase
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: Are you sure your button is not active low?

Comment: if it was active low, how would I change the code to account for that? Would I do ~resetKEY0 and ~freerunKEY1 ?

Comment: Yes, but in that situation you should also change inside always block definition `posedge ...KEY` into `negedge ...KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

Hints and tips:

- Test your buttons code by lighting one LED immediately.
- Test your divider in simulation with a small divide value.
- Run your counter without buttons, then combine them.

Note that the above works only for an FPGA. If you design an ASIC you can't do any of that. It has to work the first tine it comes out of the factory.

Officially you should synchronise your buttons to the clock and debounce them. You might not notice any bounce effects with with this code but if you want to .e.g. increment a counter by 1 for each press you will notice.

Comment: my divider in simulation is confirmed to work, I just omitted the code. This leads me to believe there is an issue with my always blocks. The frequency division is being performed if I'm correct